# How to use DMA for I2C read on Cortex M3

Tags: i2c, cortex-m, dma, atmel

I'm using an Atmel SAM3S MCU, and their ASF stuff can do I2C (they call it TWI) communications.   That's fine, except it's taking too much time from my main loop.

So, I'd like to be able to spark off a DMA transfer to read the data from the I2C device.  However, all the docs say you can't turn on TX and RX simultaneously on a half-duplex device like TWI.  The docs do show that it has a Peripheral DMA Controller (PDC) register section in the TWI registers, but I can't find any PDC examples, except for the USART, which is full duplex.

The only thing I can think of to try is to set TX section, and the next-RX section, and hope that it automatically enables RX after the TX is done.

Has anyone out there used DMA for an I2C read on the SAM3S?  If so, could you point me to some docs or examples?

Comment: If you Google for AT91 DMA TWI you will find linux drivers that do PDC for the sam3x M3 (atmel).
It's still quite some reading but the driver looked well structured and the people said it's stable.
The documentation and available code for the sam3 series from atmel is quite bad at this time, ASF is often just leading the wrong way for more than a demo approach.  

Btw, the driver uses PDC for 9+ bytes of data by #define. So they expect it to be beneficial for 9+ byte sequencial reads.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the particular part, however I would suggest that for many common usage patterns your best bet would probably be to only use DMA to handle multi-byte sequences of data.  Most I2C peripherals allow data to be read out by performing a start with a "write" address byte, and, if that is acknowledged, sending out an address or other information about what data is desired.  This is followed by a restart and a "read" address byte.  If that is acknowledged, one may then perform all but one of the byte reads with the "ack" flag set.  When that is finished, ask for the final byte to be read with the "ack" flag clear.

I'm not sure whether it would be worthwhile to use the DMA controller to clock out the bytes of the requested address, but probably not worthwhile to try to use it to clock out the first byte of the read command.

Comment: 100x per second, I want to read 14 bytes from a device running at 400kHz I2C speed, which is a significant chunk of time to use up on a 64MHz MCU that has other chores.  I understand I2C... but since it's documented as having a connection to the PDC, I thought about using that.  I'll probably end up using the TWI interrupt to run the transfer instead (although this is not much documented either)

Comment: 14 bytes, along with start and stop and a single-byte "start reading" command, would total under 400 microseconds at 400kbits/second.  If done 100x/second, that would be 4% overhead even if one was doing nothing but polling.  My inclination for that sort of data rate would probably be to have an interrupt that runs at a rate of 2kHz, and have each interrupt do 1/20 of the total work for a reading.  DMA can be hugely advantageous when tranferring hundreds or thousands of bytes; far less so when transferring 14.

Comment: I think you are mistaken supercat.
400 microseconds are a very long timespan on a microprocessor.
If you have a high performance task which needs to finish in a short amount of time you can not just wait 400uS for each TWI sensor/slave.

Comment: @John: The 400us would be worst-case if one polled 100x/second.  As noted, I would more likely split the job up into 20 interrupts.  The per-interrupt overhead will vary by CPU, of course, but a 2Khz interrupt is not especially fast and thus shouldn't be overly taxing.  With a typical I2C hardware implementation, a 2Khz interrupt should be able to avoid ever having to wait.

Comment: @supercat: But running TWI properly through interrrupts will not consume such a overhead as you described and DMA would remove the load nearly completely.
If done right the IRQ will only trigger when work has to be done (stop condition, next byte, etc) so you are not "waiting" in an IRQ, you are doing the normal CPU work. 
The main CPU task during the IRQ is to move data around, increase indexes etc. If you now add DMa (PDC) to the job then the IRQ routine will only spend very few cycles for a TWI transfer of 14 bytes. So instead of wasting 400uS cputime you can do it in one.

Comment: @John: Consider four approaches: (1) Use DMA for everything, and wait for nothing; any time one would have to wait, return from interrupt and use the next interrupt to resume processing; (2) Use one interrupt per action to finish up the previous DMA and start the next one, using whatever internal waits are needed; (3) Use as many interrupts as required to avoid waiting, not using DMA; (4) Do everything within a single interrupt, 100x/second.

Comment: @John: The software state machines required for #1 and #3 would be roughly comparable in complexity.  Approaches #2 and #4 would avoid the need to software state machines, but would "take over the system" for awhile every 10ms; #4 would take over for longer than #2.  Approach #1 would not have to interrupt the processor as many times as #3, but setting up a DMA operation often requires more work than outputting a single byte.  An advantage of approach #3 is that it may be possible to use a timer interrupt both to control the overall rate at which transactions occur, and the steps within them.

Comment: @John: My preference would probably be to use approach #3 unless the system was sufficiently devoted to sensor processing that #4 would be acceptable.  If transactions were much longer, then DMA would make more sense.